# How to show an element again which parent was toggled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a list of elements. The childs of this list are draggable. Also i have a div. If you hover over this div, I'll show my `<ul>.` If you drag an element, the `<ul>` will disappear.

Heres a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HuEGa/7/

As you see, it works. It doesn't look nice, but it works.

How can i get a animation which does the opposite of the slide i already got? If i drag something, i don't want to just hide the container, but slide it away.

I came across `$('#elementsContainer').animate({width: 'toggle'});` but then i don't know how I can make my dragged element to be shown after the container was closed.

The dragged element seems to inherit the css/states from the parent. That's why I'm setting the visibility to visible on the drag event in my example.

Any idea? I'd need a slide revert or something like that.

Edit: (Further explanation)

In the example, I'm doing `$('#elementsContainer').css('visibility', 'hidden');` so if you start dragging an `<li>` the container will disappear. This causes the child to dissapear as well. To prevent this, I'm setting the dragged item back to visible `$('.ui-draggable-dragging').css('visibility', 'visible');`

Since setting the container invisible looks ugly, I'd like to add an animation. You can try it and replace the line with some animation logic. Then you'll see, if the container gets hidden, the dragged item gets hidden as well. Now, I need to get it visible again, and here the problem occurs. I'm not able to implement an nice hide animation AND get the dragged item visible again, like I do it in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".draggable li").draggable({
    //connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    appendTo: 'body',
    start: function() {
        $('#elementsContainer').hide('slide', {
            direction: "left"
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HuEGa/8/

Comment: Wasn't able to correctly do it. I just don't know how to get it visible again.

Comment: @xotix if you hover back on the blue square it becomes visible again

Comment: I know, but the idea is to have it draged out of the container. So you drag it, you close the container and the dragged item still remains visible. I have tried a lot but somehow i don't get it. I also tried figuring out what changes are made on its css but...

Comment: @xotix i don't get exactly what you want to do, you want to hide the blue div while keeping the draggable elements visible?Please explain exactly what you need. :)

Comment: Sry, didn't thought i explained it bad. I've updated my starting post.

Comment: Got it. appendTo was the solution :) I've edited into your answer